# Compare row with all other previous string in one column and change value of another column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file named `namelist.csv`, it includes:

```
Index String             Size           Name
1     AAA123000DDD        10             One
2     AAA123DDDQQQ        20             One
3     AAA123000DDD        25             One
4     AAA123D             20             One
5     ABA                 15             One
6     FFFrrrSSSBBB        60             Two
7     FFFrrrSSSBBB        30             Two
8     FFFrrrSS            50             Two
9     AAA12               70             Two
```

I want to compare row in column `String` of each name group: if the string in each row is `match` or `is substring` of `all above rows` then remove the previous rows and sum the value of `Size` column to the value of `subtring` row.

Example: i take row 3rd: `AAA123000DDD`, i compare it to 2 row 1st and 2nd, it see that it is a match with 1st row, it will remove the 1st row then sum value of the 1st row column `Size` to the 3rd row column `Size` .
then the table will be like:

```
Index String             Size           Name
2     AAA123DDDQQQ        20             One
3     AAA123000DDD        35             One
4     AAA123D             20             One
...
```

the final result will be:

```
Index String             Size           Name
3     AAA123000DDD        35             One
4     AAA123D             40             One
5     ABA                 15             One
8     FFFrrrSS           140             Two
9     AAA12               70             Two
```

i think of using `groupby` of `pandas` to group all `Name` column, but i don't know how to apply the comparison of `String` column and sum of `Size` column.
I am new to Python so any help I will very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Name` is distinct with `String`, here's how you would do the aggregation. I kept `Name` so that it also shows in the final `DataFrame`.

```
df_group = df.groupby(['String', 'Name'])['Size'].sum().reset_index()
```

**Edit:**

To match the substrings (and using the example above that it appears that a substring will not match with multiple strings), you can make a mapping of substrings to full strings and then group by the full string column as before:

```
all_strings = set(df['Strings'])


substring_dict = dict()


for row in df.itertuples():
    for item in all_strings:
        if row.String in item:
            substring_dict[row.String] = item


def match_substring(x):
    return substring_dict[x]


df['full_strings'] = df.String.apply(match_substring)

df_group = df.groupby(['full_strings', 'Name'])['Size'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: it's work ! thanks a lot ! but i don't know that can I replace column name by column Index. Ex: instead of `df['Strings']` is df["column order"] ?? ! @Sam